# How to Create A Field That Converts Its Value to MD5 on Creation in Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, orm, peewee

I defined a model as below in Peewee:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField(null=False)
    password = FixedCharField(null=False, max_length=32)
```

The problem is that I want the field `password` to be hashed as MD5. For instance:

```
user = User.create(username="whatever", password="whatever")
user.password # returns '008c5926ca861023c1d2a36653fd88e2'
```

I use MySQL and it already has a `MD5()` function. So...

- Is there a way to use MySQL's built-in `MD5()` function? or...
- Is there a built-in way to somewhat manipulate that `Model::create` method just like Django?

---

## Environment

- MySQL 5.7.21
- Python 3.5.2
- Peewee 3.1.0

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/hacks.html#writing-custom-functions-with-sqlite has an example of hashing passwords

Comment: Wow, that was at the very end of official documentation, huh? Thanks. Keeping question alive if someone else has another solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

From the [peewee documentation hacks](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/hacks.html#writing-custom-functions-with-sqlite) page:

```
def get_hexdigest(salt, raw_password):
    data = salt + raw_password
    return sha1(data.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()

@db.func()
def make_password(raw_password):
    salt = get_hexdigest(str(random()), str(random()))[:5]
    hsh = get_hexdigest(salt, raw_password)
    return '%s$%s' % (salt, hsh)

@db.func()
def check_password(raw_password, enc_password):
    salt, hsh = enc_password.split('$', 1)
    return hsh == get_hexdigest(salt, raw_password)


query = User.insert(
    username='charlie',
    password=fn.make_password('testing')).execute()
```

Comment: These examples apply to SQLite, which supports user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with doing some kind of transformation is that you will have trouble determining whether the password was already hashed.

Since mysql has md5 builtin, you can:

```
User.create(username=username, password=fn.md5(raw_password))
```

For the love of god don't use md5, though -- it's completely broken.